# Why are group policy preference drive mappings not applied to the domain administrator account?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I have a working policy on my entire domain. I just found out, when logging with the domain administrator, that this policy is not applied (EDIT: Running : gpresult shows that the GPO's are applied - but, this GPO is for Drive Mappings, and the actual drive mappings are NOT shown)

- The administrator account - does not have any login script on his profile tab.
- **To note**: The mappings were applied before the GPO with a login script using the : net use ... command - all was working perfectly and correctly for the domain administrator user as well - That removes sharing and security problem (IMO)
- My GPO's are mainly small/atomic settings: single GPO to handle each settings: UAC, Firewall, printers.
- GPO status for the object is enabled

That's an overview of the Drive Maps:

[image]

Reading on [MS support site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816100), I checked the delegation tab, and it is marked as applied to domain and enterprise admins.

[image]

Every user gets these policies correctly.

The OU that is set is the root of the domain. (for testing purpose - I did that to eliminate hierarchy issues - did not help)

- Block Inheritance is disabled. (never used it anyway)

GPO link

[image]

GPO Security Filterings

[image]

Comment: Does the OU that the Administrator account is currently located in have 'Block Inheritance' enabled?

Comment: Domain forest? Do you mean the domain root? You can't block inheritance at the forest root. Anyway, where is the Administrator account - is it in a sub-OU of the domain or just in the default Users container?

Comment: Just the default container

Comment: Ah, just seen your response  - GPOs applied at the root of the domain should apply to users in the Users container, in the same way as it would for any other OUs. Is the GPO definitely linked at the Domain root level?

Comment: Also, what is in the Security Filtering options of the GPO?

Comment: If you run a `gpresult /R` as the Domain Administrator on one of your machines, does it show any of the policies as being in the list of ones applied? Are they showing as filtered out?

Comment: In that case I think the problem is not that the GPOs aren't being applied - it's something to do with the settings within the GPO. Are other settings from the GPOs being applied as expected?

Comment: I use atomic GPO's mainly (e.g. - single settings per GPO: firewall, UAC, login, verbose...) same for the mappings *added to question

Comment: What are the Share and NTFS permissions on the shares? Do members of the Domain Admins group have the correct Share and NTFS permissions on the shares?

Comment: If I put the same shares on a login script of : net use ......   it's ok, so I don't think it's sharing and persmissions.

Comment: @Saariko: after the account logs on, if you run gupdate /force, are the drives mapped?

Comment: no they are not, as mentioned: GPO looks like it's applied, but they are not.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you are falling foul of the fact that Domain Admins are part of a special set of groups that have their ACLs reset every hour by the domain controller.

See http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q318180 for more details

Comment: That KB article is related to membership of Distribution Groups. Moreover, it applies to Server 2000, not 2008.